# traversing dom in nested lists

Tags: jquery, dom, traversal

I am trying to traverse up nested lists to check if a check box in a parent list is checked.

```
<ul>
  <li class="isAcct"><input type="checkbox"> account 1
    <ul>
      <li class="isSchl"><input type="checkbox"> school 1
        <ul>
          <li class="isclss"><input type="checkbox"> class 1</li>
         </ul></li></ul></li></ul>
```

I am looking when I check off the input in isClss to check if the input in isAcct is checked. There will be more than 1 li in these nested lists, and multiple "isAcct" lists so i need to be specific in how I refer to it. Here is my first attempt. (I am checking in a another click but here is the logic).

```
 if($(this).closest(".isAcct").find(".acctChkr").is(":checked")){
    // parent isAcct is checked
 }else {

 }
```

I just want to know if the parent isacct input is checked when I click on the isClss or isSchl li basically.

Thanks!!

Comment: What's the question?  Is your first attempt not working for you?

Comment: First Attempt is not working, I am trying to see if the is acct check box is checked when i click on the isclass

Comment: [Your code works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/TrxUC/).  I had to add `class="acctChkr"` to the checkbox for `.isAcct`, and wire up the click handler.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('.isclss').click(function(){
      if($('.isAcct :checkbox').is(':checked')){
      }
});
```

Or, if you want to traverse up, then

```
if($(this).closest('.isAcct').find(':checkbox').is(':checked'))
```

By the way, in your question you have find(".acctChkr") but in your posted code there is no element with class `acctChkr`!

Comment: You can use [`:checkbox`](http://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/) as a less verbose alternative to `[type=checkbox]`.

Comment: @gilly3, do you mean like '.isAcct :checkbox'?

Comment: For your first example, yes. In your second example you have `.find('[type="checkbox"]')`.  That can be `.find(':checkbox')`.